# Access the collection of providers for a module in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

Is there any way for a method in a class decorated with `@Module()` to iterate over all provider objects defined for that module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access metadata by a key and module class.

For example:

```js
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('providers', UserModule));
```

Output will be like:

```js
[class UserService], [class ConfigService] ]
```

Underhood, `@Module` decorator looks like this:

```js
function Module(metadata) {
    const propsKeys = Object.keys(metadata);
    validate_module_keys_util_1.validateModuleKeys(propsKeys);
    return (target) => {
        for (const property in metadata) {
            if (metadata.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                Reflect.defineMetadata(property, metadata[property], target);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It defines a metadata by a property key (providers, controllers, imports and etc.) and saves it for a target (module class).

Metadata API: https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata#api

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much for your answer. A _much_ tidier solution to what I had before.

Comment: @Horrendo, heh, i also found a more prettier solution by injecting `DiscoveryService` from `@nestjs/core`. It has getControllers / getProviders method.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best solution, but at least it 'works for me'. I ended up defining all the provider classes in an array:

```js
const MyProviders = [ ProviderClass1, ProviderClass2, ...];
```

Then used that constant in the module definition:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [],
    providers: MyProviders,
    exports: MyProviders,
    controllers: []
})
export class MyModule {
```

I defined the constructor to include a `ModuleRef`:

```js
    public constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}
```

And then it was a relatively simple method to iterate over the instantiated provider objects:

```js
    public someMethod(): void {
        for (const cls of MyProviders) {
            const provider = this.moduleRef.get(cls.name);
            //
            // Can now call methods, etc on provider
            //
        }
    }
```

If there's a better way of doing this, I'd love to hear it.